# Finding the original git commit hash after interactive rebase

Tags: git

Let's assume I start with a simple git repository with two commits:

```
A --> B
```

I then perform an interactive rebase of the repository, modifying B, and adding a commit between the A and B. C is a new commit, and D is a modification of B.

```
A --> C --> D
```

The commit messages for B and D are different, as is the code committed.

Is it possible to determine that D is derived from B? Essentially, given the hash ID of D, is it possible to get the hash ID of B?

I suspect the answer will make use of the reflog, possibly via `git log -g`, but I've been unable to map a rebased commit to the original commit.

If this is not possible by default, is it possible to gain the information via a configuration change?

It appears it might be possible to gain this information via the `post-rewrite` hook, however, this only works if you anticipate needing this information.

Comment: Not unless you saved that information somewhere yourself. A similar situation would be if you are an a different branch, and you `git cherry-pick` something...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is it possible to determine that D is derived from B? Essentially, given the hash ID of D, is it possible to get the hash ID of B?

No, or rather, not directly:

> I suspect the answer will make use of the reflog ...

The reflog contains the information that you did a rebase, and the original SHA-1 of `B`, but not the fact that in the process of doing the rebase, you split the commit.  You could determine this heuristically (by scanning the reflog, comparing before and after IDs, and working through the parent-ID SHA-1s going backwards from `HEAD` and from the reflog entry for `B`: you'll find that commit `A` existed before and after, and `B` existed before but not after, and `C` and `D` existed after).  Commit `B` itself remains in the repository until its reflog entry expires, so that's how long you have to perform this sort of heuristic scan.

You might also find that the author date on commit `D` is the same as the author date on commit `B` (I'm not at all sure about this).

Comment: I totally agree. You can only use the commit message contents to find the corresponding commit. But, to make it more independent from the actual message, you could also add an unique identifier to each commit (eg. using git hooks) which remains always the same. Then you can search for this eg. uuid even if the message, author or timestamp has changed.